# Internship full time vs part time pay differences

Tags: salary, internship, salaried-pay

What factors will affect the pay rate for a companies internship based on whether or not you choose to work full time vs part time?

For example part time you might make more vs full time you would make less.

Comment: Hi, I edited this slightly to make it a bit better fit for the site. If I changed your intent too much, feel free to [edit] and add additional information. Great topic and welcome to the Workplace!

Answer (score 1):

> What factors will affect the pay rate for a companies internship based on whether or not you choose to work full time vs part time?

This can definitely be the case for internships. There are a few reasons there may be differences:

- **Compensation is hourly vs salaried.** This might cause you to be offered pay at an hourly rate of say $15/hour vs $2600 a month.  You may receive more benefits if offered a salaried compensation package. For technical fields, many companies have benefits packages for interns similar to full-time employees. This may be different if you are working less than 40 hours a week.
- **Difference in pay structures for part-time vs 'full-time.'** This can vary greatly based on how companies choose to pay you. My company pays interns considerably more than part-time students, even if both work 40 hours/week during summer. If you are working less than 40 hours a week, the internship pay structure may not make sense.
- **Difference in hiring departments/policies.** Many larger companies have official internship programs which are more centrally administered. HR might hire say 200 interns per year and this has a standard offer salary/rate, etc. If you are hired part-time this likely will be at the discretion of the department or single hiring manager and likely they have less budget than a large corporate policy.
- **Different expectations from part-time vs full-time.** Without some proven useful skills, it is possible a company will not pay you the same if you are working less hours. Especially for the duration of a summer, it is likely you will be able to contribute minimally in some sense and the fewer hours you are there the less likely it is you will add value to the company.
- **Less likely to feel as a 'full-time feeder'.** Many companies use internships to help determine "should we hire this person full-time?" and there is likely a higher chance for them to retain you (as well as better learn the answer to that question) if you work full-time during a summer vs only part-time.

Honestly though, while these affect things, most companies will have different perspectives on this. There is definitely not a "one answer fits all companies" perspective. For example, my company is considerably different than [Joe's company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19789/internship-full-time-vs-part-time-pay-differences#comment49035_19789) for this and I suspect most people viewing this will have slight variations in how they handle things.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I've heard of all sorts of benefits, from assistance with housing to 401k matching to the ability to buy health insurance to signing bonuses. This is going to depend based on company (and industry) a fair bit.

Comment: In the US the number of hours scheduled will determine if a set of benefits have to be offered. If an employee exceed that threshold it will impact the hourly rate they may be willing to offer.